# How return value this merge sort

Tags: algorithm, sorting, merge

Merge sort algorithm reduce the original array in a collection of 2 numbers, and put the lower before, and after sort 2 collections (1collection x 1collection), after 2x2, 3x3, etc. Finally array is sorted.
The question is: How this algorithm (the implementation in Java) sort the array if the second mergeSort(), when call mergeSort(), and merge, doesn't assign the output to an array?

I call the algorithm with:

```
int[] a = {4 , 8, 19, 7};
int[] sorted_array = mergeSort(a, 0, a.length-1);
```

---

```
static void mergeSort(int[] a)
{
    return mergeSort(a, 0, a.length - 1);
}

static int[] mergeSort(int[] a, int i, int f)
{
    if(i < f)
    {
        int h = (f + i) / 2;
        mergeSort(a, i, h);
        mergeSort(a, h + 1, f);
        merge(a, i, h, f);
    }
return a;
}

static void merge(int[] a, int i, int h, int f)
{
    int[] aux = new int[f - i + 1];
    int k = 0, iaux = i, jaux = h + 1, kaux;

while(iaux <= h && jaux <= f)
{
    if(a[iaux] < a[jaux])
    {
        aux[k] = a[iaux];
        iaux++;
    }
    else
    {
        aux[k] = a[jaux];
        jaux++;
    }

    k++;
}

while(iaux <= h)
{
    aux[k] = a[iaux];
    iaux++;
    k++;
}

while(jaux <= f)
{
    aux[k] = a[jaux];
    jaux++;
    k++;
}

kaux = 0;

for(iaux = i; iaux <= f; iaux++)
{
    a[iaux] = aux[kaux];
    kaux++;
}
```

}

Thank you.

Comment: I think you meant doubt instead of dude.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is Java "pass-by-reference"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference) (not a duplicate in the sense that it's the same question, but rather that presumably the answers to that will answer your question).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java, everything is passed-by-value. But it is important to know, what that value is!

Every variable, that is not primitive data type (int, boolean etc.) contains reference to object.

In this line `int[] a = {4 , 8, 19, 7};` you create new array and you store reference to this object in variable `a`.

If you call this method `mergeSort(a, 0, a.length-1);`, the value of variable `a` which is reference to the array is copied to the method (the second and third parameters are primitive data types, its value is copied, not reference). Therefore inside mergeSort method, it accessing directly the same array.

Comment: Java can't pass variables by reference.
But I don't know how merge() return the value. In theory, merge() lose the array sorted leaving the method.

Comment: @user3270009 - there is difference between COPYING the reference (Java) or pass by reference (C++). Java copy the reference of objects, not referencing variables. In this case, it means, that both variables - "a" in main method and "a" in mergeSort method have reference to the same object (but not to each other like in C++ when pass by reference)

Answer (score 1):

I have only skimmed the code, but it appears to modify the input array in place.  That means, if you call it like this

```
int[] a = {4, 8, 19, 7};
mergeSort(a, 0, a.length-1);
```

and then you inspect the contents of `a`, you will find it to be `{4, 7, 8, 19}`.  And if you delete the `return a;` at the end of the `mergeSort` function, *it will still work*.  Returning `a` again is just a convenience for the caller.

The internal calls to `mergeSort` and `merge` rely on this property.

In the comments you ask *how* this is being done: the key part is the loop at the very end of `merge`

```
for(iaux = i; iaux <= f; iaux++)
{
    a[iaux] = aux[kaux];
    kaux++;
}
```

which is writing to the `a` array.

Comment: But when I merge() the collections, the result is not saved! I can return a, but the array a, in theory doesn't change.

Comment: One of the following is true: you are mistaken about the result not being saved, `merge` is buggy, or I have no idea what you mean by that objection.

Comment: I do: int[] sorted_array = mergeSort(a, 0, a.length-1); and the first mergeSort will divide to a collection of 2 numbers, after the second mergeSort() will divide to a collection of 2 numbers (or 1 as defect), and merge() will sort the 2 collections, and the array a will not returned. Then, how can the array a save the sorted array?

Comment: Ah.  You do not understand what I mean by "modify the input array *in place*".  I shall attempt to improve my exposition.